# Javascript GET Data url from link when clicked

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have retrieve data from Laravel, But in view i want javascript to get url when text clicked. Example when i click **clickme** in first line i will get **/download=1** .  What the best way?

```
<a href="/download=1"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br>
<a href="/download=2"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br>
```

Comment: you have to GET  `/download=1` by ajax onclicking of the text ?

Comment: Trying to understand what you're saying.. when you click the link you want it to download the response?

Comment: you just want to get the url or what ?

Comment: i just want get url

Comment: but when you click you just want the url or you also want to change the page?

Comment: just want url save in some variable

Comment: then the anchor element is not the most suitable for this. The HTML <a> element (or anchor element) creates a hyperlink to other web pages, files, locations within the same page, email addresses, or any other URL.

Comment: @TiagoMartinho however when using a link, it is simpler to add accessibility. The title tag would be enough and you do not need to add the other element to the tab index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use a function which fires onClick of the `<a></a>` tag.

Example:

```
<a href="/download=1" onclick="getUrl(this); return false;"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br>
```

Then in Javascript you can do the following:

```
function getUrl(e) {
   var href = e.getAttribute("href");
   console.log(href);
}
```

See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5voa16f2/3/) for a working example.

Comment: How just get url without open the link?  @Chris

Comment: @IrsyadNurilhaq The `return false;` takes care of that. This code should not open the link but just `console.log()` the `href`

Comment: @IrsyadNurilhaq Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 <script>
jQuery(function($){
    $('a').click(function(event){
        if($(this).text()=='Clickme'){
          event.preventDefault();
          alert($(this).attr('href'));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by adding a common class to every  anchor tag. Like below

**HTML**

```
<a href="/download=1" class="get-url-link"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".get-url-link").click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    alert(url);
  });
});
```

Hope it will help. Let me know if you face any problem. Happy coding :)

Comment: How just get url without open the link?

Comment: You can just put return false; in your click event method.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); ...` is the preferred method to stop the link from being followed

Comment: Yes, You are right @mplungjan but he had already used it so I suggested him to use return false.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML  element (or anchor element) creates a hyperlink to other web pages, files, locations within the same page, email addresses, or any other URL. - [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

That said, I think you should create another HTML element to save the URL and for that to happen you should use the data attributes to save the url.  -
[documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

here is an dummy example of what I say above.

```js
document.getElementById('url1').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log(this.dataset.url)
});
```

```html
<div id="url1" data-url="/download=1">Click me </div>
```

Comment: However for accessibility reasons, the link is not such a bad idea

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<a id="download1" href="/download=1"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br>
<a id="download2" href="/download=2"><i class="fa fa-download"></i>Clickme</a><br> 

document.getElementById("download1").getAttribute("href");
```

Comment: Use a class instead. Much more generic

Comment: Here are two complete examples. Your code is not really complete. https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/x0qd1uf5/